# Create a simple yaml file

Tags: yaml

I really hate asking this because it should be obvious but I can't get it to work. SO I'm trying to create this simple yaml file:

```
Day:
   MOND:'1s'
   TUD:'2s'
   WED:'3s'
   THD:'4s'
   FRD:'5s'
```

But I'm getting this error:

> yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning for the next token
>   found character '\t' that cannot start any token

Answer (score 9):

It could be that you're using a tab to indent the next line, when you should be using spaces.

Comment: Never mind! I figured it out. It was using a mixture of space and tabs. Whew!